# ASP.NET MVC custom view engine - what is "{1}"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewengine

I'm having trouble finding a place where this is explained clearly.

If I have a custom view engine in my ASP.NET MVC project like this (example - I've seen this pattern used in other examples, as well):

```
public class ProjViewEngine : RazorViewEngine
{
    public ProjViewEngine()
    {
        //add new locations for the engine to look for partial views/editor templates
        base.PartialViewLocationFormats = new string[] 
        {
            // Record Partials
            "~/Views/Foo/{0}.cshtml",
            "~/Views/Foo/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
        }.Union(base.PartialViewLocationFormats).ToArray<string>();
    }
}
```

I understand when the `BarController` (for example) has a method that returns `PartialView("_Bar", model)`, it finds the view at `"~/Views/Foo/_Bar.cshtml"`.

I don't understand how/where `{1}` will get its value in `"~/Views/Foo/{1}/{0}.cshtml"`.

The `PartialView` method can only take a `string` view name and an `object` model. There's no way to specify a second string parameter.

Is it part of the routing then? From the controller name?

Comment: They are the route parameters. `0` is View, `1` controller, and `2` area.

Comment: Ah, thank you @ChristianGollhardt, that makes a lot of sense.

Comment: After seeing it again, `0` is `action` . If you return `PartialView(model)` (Note we have not set a view name) from `Bar` Action Method in `AwesomeController` it will resolve `~/Views/Foo/Awesome/Bar.cshtml`